# Error al eliminar una particion

Tags: windows7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver cada vez que voy hago clic en una de esas opciones como imagenes bibliotecas hasta el disco, me aparece esa advertencia sabiendo que ya elimine esa particion no obstante el disco c esta casi vacio y la compu se pone super lenta.
y aveces dice disco local c no responde

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece versar sobre la temática del sitio, recomiendo leer [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando entrar a "E:\Users\Desktop" cuando la partición de sistema es C:
Seguramente tú o alguien mas había movido las ubicaciones de las carpetas de la bliblioteca a la otra partición, entra con clic derecho a una de las carpetas de la biblioteca, entra en:

```
Click derecho > Propiedades > Ubicación...
```

Alli cambias la ubicación o das clic en el botón "Mover" y buscas el destino, o en "restaurar predeterminados"